# Как правильно разворачивать новые версии микросервисов в docker контейнере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, микросервисы

Всем привет, планируем пересесть на микросервисную архитектуру. У нас есть приложение на nodejs, постепенно начинаем подготавливаться к переходу.

Пока что возникло два вопроса:

1) Если наша команда правильно поняла докер, то исходники приложения должны храниться в образе. Контейнер всего лишь поднимет окружение для этого приложения. Значит ли это, что каждый релиз должен сопровождаться созданием нового образа? Если это так, какие инструменты помогут в автоматизации компановки образа с новой версией приложения и доставкой его на вебсервер.

2) Как автоматизировать процесс балансировки нагрузки? Мы бы хотели на стадии деплоя указывать количество микросервисов которое развернется на нашем сервере и автоматически натравливать балансировщик nginx на необходимые ip адреса.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Jenkins

Comment: Спасибо, @Swartex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> исходники приложения должны храниться в образе

Любое изменение внутри образа - новый образ с новой версией. 
Разверните свой приватный `docker-registry`.

> какие инструменты помогут в автоматизации компановки образа с новой версией приложения и доставкой его на вебсервер.

Docker-compose тут поможет. Используем `.env` для docker-compose [переменных](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/7607408ce748fc2f605a7ca1d7fbb40dfea3f6f0/.env), которые переиспользуем в остальных `docker-compose.*.yml` файлах.

**Как выглядит build & pull:**

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml pull
```

Дальше автоматизировать не проблема, добавляем в скрипты `jenkins`, `gitlab`, любой другой CI / CD.

> Мы бы хотели на стадии деплоя указывать количество микросервисов которое развернется на нашем сервере

Для этого используется оркестраторы `docker-swarm`, `k8s`, `nomad`. Для начала хватит `docker-swarm`. Для него нужно добавить дериктивы в `docker-compose.*.yml` файлы.

**Как пример:**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  sanic-simple-api:
    image: "$REGISTRY/${SANIC-SIMPLE-API_SERVICE}:${SANIC-SIMPLE-API_SERVICE__VERSION}"
    build:
      context: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 3s
```

Дериктива `replicas` устанавливает кол-во инстансов этого сервиса для `staging` окружения.

> автоматически натравливать балансировщик nginx на необходимые ip адреса.

Советую попробовать `traefik`. Использовав его можно динамически добавлять новые сервисы с роутингом и балансировкой. Автоматически получать и переполучать ssl сертификаты `letsencrypt` на ваши домены (многим требуется, к примеру `docker-registry`).

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  sanic-simple-api:
    networks:
      - proxy
    healthcheck:
      test: 'nc -z localhost 5000 > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      labels:
        traefik.enable: 'true'
        traefik.docker.network: traefik_proxy
        traefik.backend: sanic-simple-api
        traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method: drr
        traefik.frontend.entryPoints.http.redirect: https
        traefik.frontend.rule: '{{ services.sanic-simple-api.traefik.frontend.rule }}'
        traefik.port: '5000'
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
```

Более подробно можно ознакомиться в моем [проекте автоматизации деплоя](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup).